# Jasmine test on mock data or on real-life systems and data sources?

Tags: javascript, jquery, testing, tdd, jasmine

I have a basic question about using Jasmine BDD. Are tests meant to be simulation done on "mock" data?

I want to make a test version of an existing script, which gets data from scroll events on a web page (this script is not done). But I see Jasmine makes use of `SpecRunner.html` and `HTMLReporter` to validate the tests in the UI.

How do I use this with my own web page?

Is BDD/TDD meant to be isolated simulations to test logic? Not really connecting it with real production systems and data sources..?

Trying to grasp the basics here :)

Comment: I wrote a blog post on setting up Jasmine with JsTestDriver. It's within the context of Visual Studio, but you could adapt for your needs if you're not an MS developer: http://levelnis.co.uk/blog/running-jasmine-tests-in-visual-studio-using-jstestdriver

Answer (score 0):

yes you want to use the [Dependency Inversion Principle](http://freshbrewedcode.com/derekgreer/2012/01/22/solid-javascript-the-dependency-inversion-principle/) here. Basically you want your logic (alg) to have the DOM object (in this case a mock of the DOM object) to be passed in instead of hard coded in your logic (alg)